# Xero API and performing GET, PUT, DELETE, and POST operations in Dot net console

Tags: xero-api

I am working on a .NET C# console application, but I am having trouble finding a solution for authenticating with the Xero API and performing GET, PUT, DELETE, and POST operations. Can you provide guidance on how to achieve this?

I would like to request information from your side regarding the authentication process and how to call the Xero API in a .NET Core console application. Your guidance on these aspects would be highly appreciated.